# Fetch request to localhost with basic auth

Tags: javascript, localhost, fetch, basic-authentication

Is it possible for a webpage, like https://example.com perform an http request to localhost?

This is an uncommon situation. Let me explain:

My visitors have a local server running. They can access their server in a request to `http://localhost:12039/wallet`, which returns a json.

When the visitor opens my page (at example.com) could the JS in that page perform a request to their local server?

To make it even more complicated: the server don't add CORS header and the it also required an `Basic Auth`.

From postman, everything work as expected. But not from the browser (if not called from localhost)

[I did some tests](https://jsbin.com/qaxoxalilo/edit?js,console), but it's not working yet.

I'm not able to send the `Authorization`. When I run this code, there's a prompt from the browser, asking for username and password:
[image]

It's really hard to Google this terms. Most of the results are related to localhost calls for your own api during the development.

Comment: No CORS == No Cross Origin Resource Sharing. The browser won't allow you to make an XmlHttpRequest or fetch to it. And that's a good thing; Imagine an evil website that would try every port on your machine to check if you have local servers running. It would be disastrous. Your domain name needs to be authorized in the local server's CORS headers

Comment: Not the way you have described, because it would make a request to port 3000 on the host server.  Perhaps you could utilize ngrok so that the local server running for your visitors has a portal to the web

Comment: Also note: I'm guessing the `localhost` server is using `http` without SSL (no `https`). If that's the case, even with CORS enabled, your website **must** be served over `http` and not `https` for this to work. Otherwise, you'll get `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:12039'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`